# Split comma-separated list and prepend character to each value

Tags: javascript

I would like to turn "one,two,three,four,five" into "$one $two $three $four $five".

Here is what I have so far to separate/explode the comma-separated list.

```
var str = 'one,two,three,four,five';
var str_array = str.split(',');

for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++)
{
   // Trim the excess whitespace.
   str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
   // Add additional code here, such as:
   alert(str_array[i]);
}
```

**How can I prepend a character to each value and out them as space-separated list?**
It would be great to turn the code into a function that can be applied to a string.

Comment: You can save a little but of code if you use a regular expression for splitting: `.split(/\s*,\s*/)`.

Comment: `'$' + 'one,two,three,four,five'.replace(/,/g, " $");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```
'$' + ('one,two,three,four,five'.split(',').join(' $'))
```

Here is a function that will do it, and output an empty string if there is no matches:

```
function (s) { 
  var a = s.split(',').join(' $'); 
  return a ? '$' + a : '';
}
```

Comment: You need to treat case of an empty array separately, as this will output `'$'` then.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `+` operator and `join`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
    str_array[i] = 'a' + str_array[i];
}
var out_str = str_array.join(' ');
```

Replace `'a'` with whatever character you wish to prepend.

Comment: And use `trim()` to remove the trailing and leading whitespace

Comment: @Yogu: Not supported in IE8. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Also we can use `replace()`

```
var str = 'one,two,three,four,five';
var str_array = str.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace(',', '$');    
}
alert('$' + str);
```